# MAMP 4.1.0 on Win 10 not starting MySQL

Tags: mysql, mamp

I've installed MAMP 4.1.0 on Win 10 Home on my HP laptop (AMD Ryzen 5 processor / 8G Ram / 1TB HDD) and am having issues keeping MySQL (V.5.7.24)  running.  It defaults to ports 80 for Apache and 3306 for MySQL.  Apache starts and runs fine.  MySQL only starts upon first initial installation and it works perfectly at that point.  I can access via phpMyAdmin with no problems.  But if I shut the servers down and attempt to restart, only Apache starts, MySQL does not.  I've tried rebooting, but MySQL will NOT restart.  I've checked the MySQL error log, but nothing appears to show anything associated with the problem.  If I try to use phpMyAdmin while MySQL is shown as not up in MAMP I get the error messages shown in the attached file [phpMyAdmin Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pm7bX.png).  If anyone has any ideas on what the problem might be and what I can do to resolve this, please respond.  I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Contacted mamp support. Their answer was the following. It worked for me. Hope this helps you too.
Stop all servers in MAMP.

For MAMP:

With Windows Explorer go to folder C:\MAMP\db\mysql\ (if C:\MAMP\ is your installation directory).

First backup all files that begin with mysql-bin.*
Then delete all files that begin with mysql-bin.* (including mysql-bin.index file.)

Then try starting all MAMP servers again (wait for MySQL to turn light on).

After that stop all MAMP servers again.

You'll now try to disable binary log-bin in MAMP (or MAMP PRO)

For MAMP:
Open up MySQL configuration file in text editor of your choice:

C:\MAMP\conf\mysql\my.ini

This example assumes C:\MAMP\ is your installation directory.

Find following text:
log-bin

Comment this line by adding # character at start of line.
 #log-bin=mysql-bin

Save and restart servers

After that put the mysql-bin.* files back in their place.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. It fixed my issue.

1. Stop your MAMP Server.
2. Find the db folder for mysql. In my case: C:\MAMP\db\mysql
3. Rename the mysql-bin.index file to mysql-bin_old.index
4. Start your MAMP Server